# ApacheSolrForTypo3 cant' get result from query string

Tags: solr, typo3-8.7.x

I using TYPO3 8.7 and extension tx_solr ver. 8.1
I try to get search result from builded query. For get results my method looks like

```
public function getSolrResults ()
{
        /** @var $searchInstance \ApacheSolrForTypo3\Solr\Search */
        $searchInstance = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Search::class);

        $this->solrQuery->useRawQueryString(true);
        $this->solrQuery->useQueryString('*');
        $searchResponse = $searchInstance->search($this->solrQuery->getQuery());
        $parsedData = $searchResponse->getRawResponse();

        $responseAsArray = json_decode($parsedData, true);
        return $responseAsArray;
}
```

If I write string $this->solrQuery->useQueryString('*'), then I get full results.
If I write $this->solrQuery->useQueryString('"my request string"'), then I don't have any result. 
But I'm sure that on query "my request string" solr server will find the results.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Please share the exact syntax which your are using in case of you don't have any result.

Answer (score 0):

I got the result if I specify query field.

```
$this->solrQuery->useQueryString('title:request title')
```